# Is it valid for inline level to include block level in HTML5?

Tags: html, css

```css
div {display: inline}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Wow</p>
</div>
```

is this be valid? And if you know references related to this, please let me know.

Comment: You're confusing HTML's rules with CSS's box model. As it is, your HTML is fine because both `p` and `div` are block-level elements. Changing `div`'s style to have `display: inline` does not affect the semantics of the DOM.

Comment: don't do it, it's wrong (to be more accurate, it will give a starnge result that you won't like)

Comment: @TemaniAfif But it isn't "wrong" - it's just unusual.

Comment: @Dai it's *wrong* if we consider the expected result. It's not *wrong* from a code perspective or a validation (the Spec also clearly define how this should behave)